# Вызов переменной php в js

Tags: php, javascript, html

При нажатии на ссылку переходит сразу по линку, не вызывая `confirm`, хотя переменная `row` вызывается безо всяких проблем.

```
$testquery = "INSERT INTO education(employee_id, education_type_id, institution_id, course_name, period_from, period_till, education_document_id) VALUES($row[0], 2001134, 2001142, $coursename, $teststartdateresult, $testenddateresult, 2001149)";

$link = '<a onclick = "if(confirm(\'Send result\')) { alert('.$testquery.'); } else return false" href = "link='.$row[0].'" target = "_blank">Send result</a>';
```

При `confirm` должен алертиться запрос, в ином случае - остаёмся на странице, больше ничего.

Comment: У меня `confirm` вызывается. Можно более подробный код?

Comment: @MichaelPak чуть отредактировал тему, поменя только запрос, но от этого ничего не поменяется, я больше чем уверен.

Comment: Попробуй вставить вместо `php` переменной какую-нибудь стандартную строку, типа `Hello, world`. Может сам `javascript` не работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить кавычки в тексте алерта:

```
$link = '<a onclick = "if(confirm(\'Send result\')) { alert(\''.$testquery.'\'); } else return false" href = "link='.$row[0].'" target = "_blank">Send result</a>';
```

Странно что вы не посмотрели ошибку js в консоли браузера, тогда бы вопросов не возникло